# MediaRouter and Palette not compatible with NetStandard2.1

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

Please help!
I'm trying to run my IOS xamarin app and have the following Android error:

`code`
PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter" Version="1.2.5"
PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Palette" Version="1.0.0.8"
`code`

If I remove them then I receive this error that they are required when I run in Android.

What should I do?

Comment: It is not clear what is your structure of the project. While you are doing something wrong you haven't provided enough details to conclude what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that "Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter" and "Xamarin.AndroidX.Palette" only exist in Nuget of Android. If these two libraries are not used, delete these two libraries in all directories.
2. According to the tips of these two libraries, you need to ensure that your Android version is 9.

Comment: Thank you, I also updated my XCode to the new version 13 and it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running an iOS app, you shouldn't get an Android message, unless you accidentally added that Nuget package to your iOS solution

Check all the Nuget of the solution

[image]

Go to those Android packages.

If you check the right panel, you should see that those packages only have a version in the Android project. You should remove them from your shared or iOS project without problem.

[image]